# Pages displaying blank ONLY when Theme Developer module turned on

Tags: 7, theming

i have a situation where the theme developer module, when turned on, is causing some pages to display as the white page (of death). it's probably because i've been doing tutorials, learning how to override theme functions and probably at one point had some errors. but there errors have been cleared up, but the pages display as blank pages ONLY when that module is turned on. it's as if it has it's own cache???,

anyone know how to remedy that?, i need module to work.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to version compatibility with [Simplehtmldom](https://drupal.org/project/simplehtmldom) module.

Download this [library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/latest/download) and install in your sites/libraries files.

This is taken from modules page,

> **NOTE**: Currently, Theme Developer does not work with the latest version of simplehtmldom API. You must use simplehtml API version
>   7.x-1.12 if you want Theme Developer to function properly.

OR if that is not the case you can try putting this snippet end of  the settings.php file, this snippet will show error message on the browser while loading page instead of **WSOD**. and you can put your error message here in question and elaborate it.

```
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

Comment: And library version? What error message you got after putting that snippet on settings.php file ?

Comment: i added the snippet but still getting a blank page. my settings file is a little different as its an Acquia Dev desktop set up. maybe the error reporting snippet is not being read?

Comment: when i go to load the page, it hangs for what seems a long long time. during which my computer heats up ;-)  from trying to process something

Comment: by the way, i cleared the cache after adding the snippet

Comment: do you have libraries module installed ?? https://drupal.org/project/libraries